# The correct definition for function?

Tags: functions

I searched the internet for the definition of function and I found alot of different things.

There definitions say that function is a rule and there others say that is ordered pairs and another definitions that say it's an ordered triple.

So can one explain explicitly the correct definition of function with telling the intuition behind this definition ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I define exactly what a function is?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917581/how-do-i-define-exactly-what-a-function-is)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087412/what-is-a-function)